# Как расположить точки, чтобы получить нужное закругление прямой?

Tags: svg, анимация, математика

У меня есть 4 координаты (2 для обозначения начала и конца прямой, 2 для того, чтобы показать на сколько она закругляется).

Она рисуется вот так (в SVG):

```
<path class="arrays" d="M'+start_x+','+start_y+' C600,400 530,356 '+end_x+','+end_y+'"  />
```

Берем `start_x`, `start_y`, `end_x`, `end_y` - любые. 
По этим координатам мы можем построить прямую, но мне нужно как-то высчитать, как необходимо расположить 2 средние координаты (точки): `600,400` и `530,356`, чтобы фигура имела нужное мне закругление, т.е. на `30` или `45` градусов с каждого конца. + точки должны перемещаться в зависимости от того, где находятся координаты начала и конца.

Кто подскажет как сделать? Есть какие-нибудь формулы?

Comment: Вы не могли бы уточнить, что означает "закругление прямой"? Прямая — она, знаете ли, прямая.

Comment: Думаю, что автор, все-таки, имеет ввиду не прямую, а кривую и играется с какими-то углами.    
Но определение "закругленности", все-таки, стоило бы дать

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, всё-таки, задача не о прямой, а о кривой.
Во-вторых, если я правильно понимаю, то закругленность — это угол между прямой, соединяющей точки концов и касательной в одном из концов.
Если так, то всё просто:
Т.к. у тебя с обоих концов должен быть один и тот же угол, то ты просто получаешь равнобедренный треугольник, с известными координатами точек основания и заданными углами. Найти тебе нужно 3-ю вершину — задача не очень сложная)

Answer (score 2):

По образцу кода в вопросе,- это Кубическая кривая Безье.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробно [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=907)

Изменяя координаты контрольных точек `x1,y1` и `x2,x3` можно получить любую форму кривой Безье.

Можно это делать вручную, но удобней воспользоваться онлайн генератором кривых:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[В онлайн редакторе кривых](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1114) двигаем контрольные точки и/или начальные, финальные точки для получения нужной формы кривой и копируем код:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  
  
<path
    fill="dodgerblue"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="3"
    d="M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154 " />
</svg>
```

### Анимация кривой

*С сохранением позиции начальной и конечной точек кривой - `mx,my` и `x,y`, изменяем только координаты контрольных точек*

1. `<path d="M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154 ">`
2. `<path d="M101,154 C98,280 281,280 290,154">`

Анимируем параметр `"d"` патча

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  
  
  <path
     fill="dodgerblue"
     stroke="black"
     stroke-width="3"
     d="M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154 " >
  
  <animate
      attributeName="d"
      values="M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154;M101,154 C98,280 281,280 290,154;M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154"
      dur="4s"
      fill="freeze"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

**Изменяем позиции начальной и конечной точек кривой - mx,my и x,y**

1. `<path d="M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154 " />`
2. `<path d="M51,154 C98,26 281,26 341,154 " />`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  
  
  <path
     fill="dodgerblue"
     stroke="black"
     stroke-width="3"
     d="M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154 " >
  
  <animate
     attributeName="d"
     values="M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154;M51,154 C98,26 281,26 341,154;M101,154 C98,26 281,26 290,154"
     dur="4s"
     fill="freeze"
     repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  
  
  
  
</svg>
```